# iOS Blue tooth low energy signal sending in background

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to have an iphone (iphone 1) send out BLE signals in the background with information such as an id number and time sent?  This signal will be read by another iphone (iphone 2) running the BLE app in the foreground.  iphone 2 does not need to communicate with iphone 1.  It just needs to recieve the signal which i know it can, but i'm just not sure if iphone 1 will be able to send out this signal in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using iBeacon - no, it can't.

If you use the underlying BTLE support via `CBPeripheralManager` - yes, it can.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I looked up CBPeripheral Apple Documentation and it mostly talks about RECEIVING signals from other peripherals.  I am looking for some documentation about SENDING signals and sending them preferable while running in the background.  Can you point me in the right direction of that kind of documentation? I cant seem to find it.

Comment: You're looking for advertising (that's what the peripheral does). `CBCentralManager` instances scan for advertising peripherals.

Comment: @Wain he's looking for `CBPeripheralManager`...that way he can emulate  a `CBPeripheral`

Answer (score 0):

To have iPhone 1 act as a peripheral (sending data) in the background, make sure you add (in your Info.plist file), "Required background modes" -> "App shares data using CoreBluetooth".

This project lets you easily set up an iPhone to share an array of strings while in background mode with another iPhone in foreground mode: [SimpleShare](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share)